# What is the work of "tf.nn.embedding_lookup"

Tags: tensorflow, text-classification, word-embedding, embedding-lookup

I am trying to implement Embedding layer for text classification using CNN.
Embedding layer
`with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
      self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),name="W")
      self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W, self.inputTensor)
      self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars, -1)`

I couldn't understand [tf.nn.embedding_lookup](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) working.

Answer (score 0):

> This function is used to perform parallel lookups on the list of tensors in params.

It is generalized form of `tf.gather`. This example will clear the working of the `tf.gather` and `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`.

Suppose you have a tensor of shape (1), containing strings. Let's call it params.

**PARAMS**

|.  0.  |.  1.  |.  2.  |.  3. |.  4.  |.  5.  | <= index

|. a1. |. a2. |. a3. | a4. |. a5. | a6  |  <= values

Let Id be another tensor of int32 or int64

**IDS**

[ 2, 3]

Then this function returns the values at these indices in the params as another tensor.

In the above case it returns.
[ a3, a4]

[This image should make it clear](https://www.tensorflow.org/images/Gather.png)

So in your above example ,  self.W 's value at indices pointed by self.InputTensor are extracted by the tf.nn.embedding_lookup function.

Comment: So in my example, self.W is the params and self.InputTensor is indices!!

Comment: Yes W is param and Input tensor is indices